# How to get row number in SlickGrid by pressing the Enter key-Solved

Tags: get, row, slickgrid

Seems like a simple task but I have been unsuccessful so far using Slickgrid to get the row number of the highlighted row in a grid when I press a key, specifically the Enter key. I need no data, just the row number so I can use it to reference an array element.

I have managed to do this with the mouse using the onDblClick event handler but not with the simple onKeyDown handler.

Here is the function I use to fill the grid with data which I call when specifically needed:

```
var grid;
function ttesting(){
    var data=[];    
    load_text_resource(descsource); 
    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
    grid.invalidate();

//load data from multidimensional array:

    for (var i = 0; i < maxdesc-2; ++i) {
        data[i] = {
            aName: descarray[i][2] + " " + descarray[i][3] + descarray[i][4] + descarray[i][5] + descarray[i][6],
            aTitle: descarray[i][8],
            aDesc:descarray[i][9]        
         }; 
    }
    grid.setOptions(options);

// the following mouse handler works:

    grid.onDblClick.subscribe(function(event) {    
        var cell = grid.getCellFromEvent(event),
        row = cell.row; 
        alert(descarray[row][10]);
});

//This keyDown handler does not work:

    grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(function(event) {
        var cell = grid.getCellFromEvent(event),
        row = cell.row; 
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            alert(descarray[row][10]);
        }
    }
    grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel());  
    grid.render();
}
```

All I need to know is the row number of the highlighted row when I press the Enter key. I have also tried using instead in the above with no success:

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
   selectRow = grid.getSelectedRows();
   alert(selectRow);
}
```

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: note that all SlickGrid events are only applied to the grid container, in other words if you're doing Enter key while not being focused in the grid (or a cell in the grid) then it won't trigger anything and if that is the case you should subscribe to your own global click event (not the SlickGrid one) from the body maybe

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to do this is to create a custom formatter for the ID column, and embed the value (ie. the row id) into the button or link displayed. For example, here's an edit link that I use to open an external page:

```
function EditLinkFormatter(rowIndex, cell, value, columnDef, grid, dataProvider) {
  if (value == null || value === "" || !columnDef.hyperlink) { return "-"; }
  if (typeof value == 'string') { value = urlEncode(value); }
  return '<a href="' + columnDef.hyperlink.replace("[id]", value) + '" target="_blank">edit</a>';
}
```

This uses `value`, which is the value of the ID column for the row, but `rowIndex` is what you are after. It's there in the formatter parameters too.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.  I needed to include the args variable in the event function:

```
grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(function(event,args) { 
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var cell = args.cell,
        row = args.row;
        alert(descarray[row][10]);
    }
});
```